# Prevent flex container from overflowing viewport

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a fluid layout consisting of a header, body and footer all of which should always be in view.

The problem
If an element is applied outside of flex layout then the elements are pushed outside of the viewport by the height of the external element. How can I maintain an always in view layout that's agnostic of external element dimensions so that elements are always viewable?

```css
.main {
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
}

.external-element-no-control {
  height: 70px; // could be any height
  background: black;
}

.content-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.blocks {
  flex: 1;
}

.one {
  background: cyan;
  flex: 0;
}

.two {
  background: lightGreen;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.three {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="external-element-no-control"></div>
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="block one">
        <div>
          <h1>This is my title </h1>
          <p>With some sub text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="block two">
        <div>This is my main content</div>
      </div>
      <div class="block three">
        <div>This is my call to action</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the `.bar` element supposed to be the header?

Comment: Hey, I've updated the markup - so there is an element external-element-no-control which is the element that could be any height pushing the flex layout down

Comment: Where is the external element supposed to be? On top of the page contents? Or do you want to shrink the size of the page to fit the external element to fit?

Comment: @NathanFries yeah I want to shrink the content to allow for the external element height dimensions and keep all elements visible

Comment: Does the "external element" have any known (consistent) IDs or class names?

Comment: You have `.blocks` in your css. Should probably be `.block`

Comment: @NathanFries the "external element" or elements could be elements injected in by third parties for example with no known dimensions but the main aim is for the flex layout to continue to display the flexed elements within the 100% viewport \

Comment: Do you have any control over the placement of the external element? e.g. will it always be the first child of `.main`?

Answer (score 1):

Use another flex container on the parent element. This will enable your child elements to consume remaining space without having to define heights.

Give the `body` element `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column`.

Give the external element `height: auto`, so it adjusts to the content height.

Give the main content `flex: 1`, so it consumes any remaining space.

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qjkvgtum/)

```css
.main {
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.external-element-no-control {
  color: white;
  background: black;
  min-height: 0;
}

.content-wrapper {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.blocks {
  flex: 1;
}

.one {
  background: cyan;
  flex: 0;
}

.two {
  background: lightGreen;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.three {
  background: pink;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="external-element-no-control">could<br>be<br>any<br>height</div>
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="block one">
        <div>
          <h1>This is my title </h1>
          <p>With some sub text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="block two">
        <div>This is my main content</div>
      </div>
      <div class="block three">
        <div>This is my call to action</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I should point out I have no control over any elements outside of content wrapper, that’s my biggest challenge

Comment: What do you mean by "no control"? I gather from your question that you meant no control of height.

Comment: Your example still requires scrolling to see the call to action section

Comment: The content (in this case, the text) has a fixed height. What do you want your content to do on short screen heights? There's no way to completely avoid a vertical scroll bar unless you want the content to shrink to 0 height.

Comment: We don't need to worry about on a mobile screen, the main aim for now is to make sure that an element(s) can be added to the DOM and the flexed layout can continue presenting all elements without scrolling

Comment: I had uploaded an incomplete demo. My final version had the `height: 100%` rules removed. Answer revised. Test it again.

Comment: Is there an alternative to applying flex styles and heights to .main? I'll really only have access to .content-wrapper and it's children - think of it as living inside an iframe with the external elements all part of the page that's embedded me

Comment: Got it. Then CSS may not work for you. Look into a JS solution.